# RichTextBox: using RichTextBox.Selection.start etc with tabbed content

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I wish to underline selected text but find that the underlining continues to the next tab-
stop

sample code

```
 //rtbList is a richTextBox
        rtbList.AppendText("\t");  
        selStart = rtbList.TextLength;
        rtbList.AppendText("Bought"); 
        rtbList.SelectionStart = selStart;           
        rtbList.SelectionLength = rtbList.TextLength - selStart;
        rtbList.SelectionFont = hdgFont; // bold & underline
        rtbList.AppendText("\t");
        //
        selStart = rtbList.TextLength;
        rtbList.SelectionLength = 0;
        rtbList.AppendText("Maturity");
        rtbList.SelectionStart = selStart;            
        rtbList.SelectionLength = rtbList.TextLength - selStart;
        rtbList.SelectionFont = hdgFontNoUnderline;
```

Is there anyway to overcome this or is it a basic "flaw" in the rtf format?

[Clearly I could avoid this by using a fixed format e.g. "Courier" and constructing strings

with spaces to align text.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your selStart happens before the `AppendText("\t")` line.  Your NoUnderline font is not including the range that includes the Tab.

Essentially, any text that you append after the underline font is getting that font until you change it.

```
rtbList.AppendText("\t");  
selStart = rtbList.TextLength;
rtbList.AppendText("Bought"); 
rtbList.SelectionStart = selStart;           
rtbList.SelectionLength = rtbList.TextLength - selStart;
rtbList.SelectionFont = hdgFont; // bold & underline

//Move before AppendText:
selStart = rtbList.TextLength;

rtbList.AppendText("\t");
rtbList.SelectionLength = 0;
rtbList.AppendText("Maturity");
rtbList.SelectionStart = selStart;            
rtbList.SelectionLength = rtbList.TextLength - selStart;
rtbList.SelectionFont = hdgFontNoUnderline;
```

Comment: Thanks LarsTech  That certainly answers the query

Comment: it certainly answers the problem as posed.  BUT what I am really attempting is to restrict underlining to the non-space characters! Any  thoughts?

Comment: @MartinLord Whatever is selected in the RTB and you apply a font will get that font.  You need to just exclude the non-spaced characters from your underline font, or the other way around, include the non-spaced characters when applying the non-underlined font, which is what my solution did.  There is no magic formula for excluding non-spaced characters from receiving a particular font.  You have to select your range and apply your font.

Comment: The problem , I believe arises because the non-space charaters are not explicit in the text being added but are white space from the end of the text up to the PIXEL coordinate specified by the tab. Selection start, length relate to characters . The tab position wont neccessarily be an integral character position nor will the trailing white space before the tab be an integral number of characters. I am beginning to conclude that the only(?) way to do what I want is to use Graphics.DrawString at the required tab positions. Thanks your comments.